# Subtraction of two repeating decimals

Tags: rational-numbers, decimal-expansion

When I was looking at the proof that every repeating decimal is rational, I came across this example:

$x=5.33333333\ldots$ ($3$ repeat indefinitely)

$10x=53.3333333\ldots$ ($3$ repeat indefinitely)

My question is why $10x-x = 53-5$?

Why is it possible to subtract the infinite part of $x$ and $10x$?

Why is $0.33333\ldots - 0.3333\ldots = 0.0000\ldots$ is this really a zero?

Comment: Think of it this way: it's smaller than every other number. The only number like this is $0$. (I'm restricting myself to talking about positives, but the basic idea is the same regardless.)

Comment: Or: $.33\overline3$ is the number that $0.3,0.33,0.333,0.3333,\text{etc.}$ "get closer and closer to." Now, $.00\overline0$ is the number that $0.0,0.00,0.000,\text{etc.}$ "get closer and closer to." Rewriting that slightly, we have—it's the number that $0,0,0,0,\text{etc.}$ "get closer and closer to"—which is, of course, $0$. (I'm skipping some details.)

Comment: You can't explain mathematics that way, it's all about the detail, we are not in the field of physics so something close to 0 is not 0. look at "egreg" answer and you'll understand.

Comment: I said I was skipping over some details. Here's a more complete version: for an infinite decimal $.abcd\dots$, give it a sequence $A_n$ such that $A_1=.a$, $A_2=.ab$, $A_3=.abc$, etc. The infinite decimal $.abcd\dots$ is defined as the number $x$ such that, for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $N$ such that for all $k>N$, $|x-A_k|<\epsilon$.

Comment: It can be shown that that $x$ is unique. This means that every infinite decimal has one value, which is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This argument is actually not a proof, unless you have already proved that repeating decimal alignments really define a rational number *and* that you can do multiplication by $10$ just by shifting the decimal point.

This is an indication that *if* $5.(3)$ (this is how a repeating decimal is often represented) defines a rational number $x$ and *if* multiplication by $10$ on these objects obeys the same rules as for finite decimal numbers, then
$$
10x-x=53-5=48
$$
so the only possible choice of $x$ is $x=48/9=16/3$.

The repeating decimals are instead associated to a number with the concept of a series:
$$
5.(3)=5+\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{3}{10^k}
$$
just like the finite decimal $5.333$ is
$$
5+\frac{3}{10}\frac{3}{100}+\frac{3}{1000}
$$
The series above is a geometric series and its sum is known to be
$$
\frac{3}{10}\frac{1}{1-\dfrac{1}{10}}=\frac{3}{10}\frac{1}{\dfrac{9}{10}}=
\frac{3}{10}\frac{10}{9}=\frac{1}{3}
$$
so that
$$
5.(3)=5+\frac{1}{3}=\frac{16}{3}
$$
by definition.

If $0<r<1$, the sum of the series
$$
\sum_{k\ge1}ar^k=ar\frac{1}{1-r}
$$
For $0.(23)$, the series would be
$$
\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{23}{10^{2k}}=\frac{23}{100}\frac{1}{1-\dfrac{1}{100}}
=\frac{23}{99}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$.3333... = \dfrac{1}{3}$$

So

$$10x-x = \left(53+\frac{1}{3}\right)-\left(5+\frac{1}{3}\right) = 53-5$$

Comment: yes, but that's like using the solution to answer the question. Im trying to prove that .3333...=1/3.

Answer (score 1):

Let x=5.333333....
Multiplying x by 10:
$$10x = 53.333333...=53+0.333333....\\$$
And
$$10x-53 = 0.333333...\\$$
Multiplying x by 100:
$$100x=533.333333... \\$$
$$100x= 533+0.333333....\\$$
$$100x=533+10x-53\\$$
$$\implies100x-10x = 533-53 =480\\$$
$$\implies90x=480\implies x=\frac{480}{90}=\frac{16}{3}\\$$

Comment: you didn't understand my question, you are oversimplifying things. Look at the accepted answer.

Comment: Sorry, I was aware of that later. Sorry again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)